# How to make a div's position outside of a wrapper relative to a div inside a wrapper?

Tags: css, width, wrapper, html, css-position

I need some help. I am going to school for graphic design and am building a website as a trade of services.

I designed the template in photoshop and then put it through PSD2CSSOnline.com which spat out the code and spliced images.

I was able to edit the HTML and CSS enough to get the two pink lines across the top to stretch across the browser, but I have no clue how to get the bottom ones to do the same since the text on different pages will vary and I assume the div has to be outside of the wrapper to stretch the 100% width so my problem is how to do that AND STILL MAKE IT RELATIVE to the div inside the wrapper?

Any help is appreciated, I have spent hours trying to figure this out!

For reference I have uploaded it so you can look at the source code and visually see what I am talking about. To view it go here: http://bellairo.com/anytime/

Answer (score 0):

i'm not very familiar with psd-css kinda programs so this is a bit hard to understand... for the top purple lines it seems like you have 2 images: 1 is 960 x 30px Layer-13.png, and then there is the 24 x 30px Layer-12-rx.png that repeats into infinity in both directions underneath that. It seems the simplest to get that same png image - Layer-12-rx .png to do the same thing at the bottom of your page - repeat this image underneath the one that is already there: Layer-7.png.

As far as your question about the lines being relative to your content: I notice that almost all your divs have position:absolute applied to them. Be careful of this because when that attribute is applied, it removes the div from the normal flow of how css positions things and then you have to start specifying everything, instead of divs just following upon each other naturally - which is good for things like having your bottom lines just naturally positioning themselves underneath your content, however much there is. The div in which your footer lines are sitting also has this position: absolute applied to it, which means you are always going to have to tell it exactly where to sit for every page. A start is to change it to position: relative and then play with the left: and top: values until it's in the right place. Then it should position itself underneath the text every time.
Good reference is W3 schools - for positioning info check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp